# RestAssured, JSON: verify absence of a value in a field

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

I have the following example URI:

```
localhost/users
```

and this JSON coming as response when I send a request to it:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Joe"
,
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Ben"
,
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Jim"
    }
  }
]
```

How do I verify with RestAssured, for example that there are no user with id = 2?

Would it be something along the lines of this semi-pseudo:

```
 given().spec(requestSpecification)
                .when().get("/users")
                .and().body("id==2", ????);
```

Any advice/guidance will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```java
given().spec(requestSpecification)
                .when().get("/users")
                .and().body("id", is(not(equalTo(2))));
```

Usage rest-assured documentation section [Use the response to verify other parts of the response](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#use-the-response-to-verify-other-parts-of-the-response) provides more detail.

`is(not(Matcher))` is provided by [hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#not(org.hamcrest.Matcher))

Comment: isNot? It just not in the list of variants when im trying to write it there...